# Index in WHERE condition only appears in "POSSIBLE_KEYS"

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query in MySQL 5.7 like:

```
select c1,count(distinct c2) as cnt from tbA 
where c3 >= '2020-09-01 00:00:00' and c3 < '2020-09-02 12:00:00' 
group by 1
```

I put general index on c1,c3 respectively BUT explain shows:

```
SELECT_TYPE: SIMPLE
POSSIBLE_KEYS: c1,c3
KEY: c1
```

Why index of c3 only appears in "POSSIBLE_KEYS" and not finally used? How to user this index?

---

Table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbA` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `c2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `channel_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c3` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `audit_create` timestamp(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
  `audit_update` timestamp(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_uid` (`c1`),
  KEY `login_time` (`c3`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: `c3` stores DATETIME value but it has VARCHAR datatype.

Comment: @Akina Yes. This table is transfered by logstash JDBC output plugin and the original `postgres` table's time column is type of `text`. So I store the time using `varchar` but the column itself is indexed

Comment: Only one index can be used in the query here. So the optimizer has to chose on of the possible ones. You may want to experiment with composite indexes on the two columns here and check if that improves the performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL (and probably every other database) only uses *one* index to access a table.

What the explain plan is telling you is that it is considering using either index, `c1` and `c3`, but it decides that `c1` is best.

You can marginally help the query by using a composite index on `(c1, c3)`.  However, you cannot use *two* separate index on the same table reference.